# How do I clear the browser's auto-complete history?

Tags: auto-correct, privacy

My phone keeps saving what I type into chrome or the browser. I have tried erasing the history it still auto completes if I need to retype it. I understand it great to save all the info but I have typed my credit card in one of them and its saved.

How do I clear the browser's address bar auto-complete history?

Answer (score 1):

If it is auto-completed by Google Chrome, please follow the following steps,

1. Go to your [Google Account Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard). This will list all of the information collected on you by Google.
2. Scroll down to `Web History` and search for your Credit Card entry or other entries to be removed, and remove it from the history. Or you can go directly to your [Web History](https://history.google.com/history/lookup?st=web).
3. Further, in Dashboard you can scroll down to `` `Chrome Sync `` and click on `Manage Chrome Sync`.
4. Click on the `Stop and Clear` button to clear all the `Autofil` and
   `Omnibox History` and to stop syncing the data with Google Server.

Steps 3 & 4 will merely stop Google from collecting data on Google Chrome's Omnibar (I am not 100% certain on this).

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold the offending autofill suggestion.  A pop up appears to "remove a Learned word".